# SQLalchemy creates Database, but not tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to connect my FastAPI project to 2 databases, one is gonna be local and the other one is located in an IP address. I think I managed to connect to both. However, when I try to create the local db, I get the file of the file, but is not pulling the models that I created for that db.

my code for database.py is the following:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "credentials and address"
AUTH_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./users.db"


engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
engine2 = create_engine(AUTH_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={
                        "check_same_thread": False})

Base = declarative_base()
BaseB = declarative_base()

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
SessionLocal.configure(binds={Base: engine, BaseB: engine2})
```

The models I created for that base are the following:

```
class User(BaseB):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String)

    ##Constraints##
    leads = relationship("Lead", back_populates="owner")

    def verify_password(self, password: str):
        return hash.bcrypt.verify(password, self.hashed_password)


class Lead(BaseB):
    __tablename__ = "leads"
    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.Id"))
    first_name = Column(String, index=True)
    last_name = Column(String, index=True)
    email = Column(String, index=True)
    company = Column(String, index=True, default="")
    notes = Column(String, default="")
    date_created = Column(String, default=datetime.utcnow)
    date_last_update = Column(String, default=datetime.utcnow)

    ##Constraints##
    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="leads")
```

Also, I created a services.py file, which I use to run the code to create the database. It's creating the users.db file, but when I try to open it, I don't get the tables I created:

```
from database import BaseB, engine2, SessionLocal


def create_database():
    return BaseB.metadata.create_all(bind=engine2)


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

This is causing me problems, because I need to post data to the table users. However, when I try to do it, I get an error saying there is no such table created. I've tried even to run the code to generate the db automatically (without running services.py on python) but still I get the same error.

I would appreciate if someone can take a look at my code and check what I may be missing.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

I think I have figured out what was wrong. I post this solution in case anyone else might get trapped as I was. My error was that I wasn't importing the models, neither declaring it in the services.py route. I changed my code and now I can see the two tables when I create the database from python

```html
from database import engine2, SessionLocal
import models


def create_database():
    return models.BaseB.metadata.create_all(bind=engine2)
```

Hope it helps anyone having the same problem :)